# html onClick event won't fire with vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am writing a vba program to interact with a website and automatically fill the form. I have gotten other types of links to work, but there are some links that expand hidden sections of the form. These will not work when using the code below. I need to know if there is a way to do this.

Here is the html source code:

```html
<a name="diForm:addProductSizeLnk" id="diForm:addProductSizeLnk" style="float: right;" 
onclick="jsf.util.chain(document.getElementById('diForm:addProductSizeLnk'),
event,'jsf.ajax.request(\'diForm:addProductSizeLnk\',event,{execute:\'@none \',
render:\'@none \',onevent:function(data){showEditor(data,\'diForm:productSizeEditor\',
\'diForm:productSizeAddDiv\', false ? \'diForm:in_clinicallyRelSizeText\' :
\'diForm:in_clinRelSizeType\')},\'javax.faces.behavior.event\':\'action\'})');
return false;" href="#">
```

I have correctly referenced the link and am using the following code:

```
For j = 0 To objCollectionA.Length - 1
    If objCollectionA(j).Name = "diForm:addProductSizeLnk" Then
        objCollectionA(j).FireEvent ("onclick")
    End If
Next
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In amazon site, its not as simple as to call the event. Find the parent form for the control and after all inputs just submit that form.

Comment: Could you please post the entire VBA code, including `objCollectionA` variable initialization. Have you tried `oIE.document.getElementById("diForm:addProductSizeLnk").click`? And don't forget to wait until the element is ready. Also to simulate a click you can create mouse event object `Set oMouseEvt = oIE.document.createEvent("MouseEvents")`, initialize it `oMouseEvt.initMouseEvent "click", True, True, .document.parentWindow, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, False, False, True, False, 0, ""`and dispatch it to the target element `oIE.document.getElementById("diForm:addProductSizeLnk").dispatchEvent oMouseEvt`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [omegastripes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2165759/omegastripes) for your comment. I thought I was waiting using `Do While IE.Busy   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)   Loop` as well as the .readyState function. I noticed that the program was completing though, before the `objCollectionA(j).FireEvent ("onclick")` took effect. So I stepped through the code slowly and it worked. Now I am using `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", t, Now)` to pause the program for a few seconds. I also am cleaning up the code a bit by using `IE.document.getElementById("diForm:addProductSizeLnk").click` instead of using While-Wend to call from a collection. This is still pretty new to me as you can probably tell.

> And don't forget to wait until the element is ready.